# Accessing jQuery within a JavaScript namespace / module pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, scope, module-pattern

I'm using the following as a namespace pattern:

```
var myApp = {

    targetUri: '/path/to/api',

    poll: function()
    {
        $.getJSON(targetUri, null, function(data)
        {
            // ...
        });
    }
};
```

However, I'm getting an error that `$` is undefined on the `getJSON` line. I'm guessing that the `$` object doesn't get scope inside the namespace. How can I resolve this?

I've tried using the `= function()` variant of the pattern (module pattern), but this is blocked by Content Security Policy (CSP) as part of `unsafe-eval`.

Comment: `$` will be declared globally, so you shouldn't have trouble accessing it in any scope. If `$` is undefined, that means you didn't include jQuery on your page (or the path to the file is wrong). In addition, you can't just access `targetUri` like that (it's not a variable)...you'll need to use `this.targetUri` or `myApp.targetUri`

Comment: Oh, wow, I feel like an idiot. I'd loaded the wrong damn header into my view, so it was missing the jQuery include. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.